# C++ If/Else statements getting skipped

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am writing a Craps program as a school assignment. In this code, no matter what the dice roll is, the program skips over all the "if" blocks and continues past the last line in this snippet. The random number generator is set to generate numbers 1-12 only so each return is within that range.

```
int diceRoll = ThrowDice();

if (diceRoll == '7' || diceRoll == '11')
{
    cout << "\nCongratulations! You won!!";
    didWin = true;
    UpdateBalance(didWin, bet);
}
else if (diceRoll == '2' || diceRoll == '3' || diceRoll == '12')
{
    cout << "\nYou lose!";
    didWin = false;
    UpdateBalance(didWin, bet);
}
else if (diceRoll == '1' || diceRoll == '4' || diceRoll == '5' || diceRoll == '6' || diceRoll == '8' || diceRoll == '9' || diceRoll == '10')
{
    int diceRollPoint = PlayPointRound(diceRoll);
    if (diceRollPoint == '7')
    {
        cout << "\n\nSorry, you lose!";
        didWin = false;
        UpdateBalance(didWin, bet);
    }
    else if (diceRollPoint == diceRoll)
    {
        cout << "\n\nYou won!!!";
        didWin = true;
        UpdateBalance(didWin, bet);
    }
}
```

Comment: use nested if, if you want to check all the cases, generally if else if will terminate after one of the condition is satisfies and won't check next all else if statements. so use if... if , if u want to check all the cases.

Comment: @AviPatel It does not necessarily need to check all 3 conditions. If it matches the first condition, it would be fine for it go go strait into that block and execute. However, it does not even do that.

Comment: @Andrew You should accept one of the answer's below

Comment: @epistemophiliac It didn't let me select an answer so quickly, and I got distracted continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `'7'` means something different than writing `7`.

The former is a charcter literal, which is understood as the integer code corresponding to that character, the other is just the integer 7.

Comment: Solid answer. Perfectly explained. Solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your dice rolls are represented as `int`s, but you're comparing them to `char` literals. You should use `int` literals by removing the quotes. E.g.:

```
int diceRoll = ThrowDice();
if (diceRoll == 7 || diceRoll == 11) {
    // Here ----^----------------^
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for giving an explanation as well.